# Cant login to mssql via typeorm

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

[Error from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNGAD.png)

I used the same id and password to connect to the same database using MS SQL Server management studio, but when I connect in typeorm, the error pops out as shown in the attachment.
the following is my script to connect the database

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";

createConnection({
    type: "mssql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    username: "root",
    password: "12345",
    database: "ABC",
    entities: [
    ],
    extra: {
      options: {
        encrypt: false
      },
    },
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}).then(connection => {
    // here you can start to work with your entities
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: You should open SQL Server error log and find there the error "login failed". The next row will give you a detailed description of this "login failed"

Comment: cant find any log in the audit folder

Comment: Log on using SSMS (you said you can do it), in query window type exec xp_readerrorlog

Comment: The default path for errorlog is NOT audit folder, it's smth like this: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL_2012\MSSQL\Log. But you'll do first to query it from SSMS

Comment: found it, thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

looks like the port number provided is wrong. Please correct your port number. The default port number for MSSQL is  1433